# how to translate worksheet formula to vba formula?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I wrote this in vba. There's no error when I try, but I cannot get any number in Num
Maybe the translation bet Worksheet ⇄ VBA is not correct.

```
Dim Num As Integer
Num = WorksheetFunction.Match(1, WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.N(Range("A:A") = "XXX"), 0), 0)
```

Anyone has the solutions?

P.S.

> I solved this problem with Evaluate formula like below

```
Num = Worksheet(sheet1).Evaluate("MATCH(1,INDEX(N(A:A=""XXX""),0),0)")
```

Thank you for everyone to reply.

Comment: Can you post the worksheet formula you are trying to translate?

Comment: Hi ! This is the original formulra from the worksheet. And this works.
=MATCH(1,INDEX(N(A:A="XXX"),0),0)

Comment: You can't translate a formula like that into VBA using WorksheetFunction, try using Evaluate instead.

Comment: This is an array formula. You translate them to VBA by creating a `For Each` loop over the affected cells.

Comment: Your formula `=MATCH(1,INDEX(N(A:A="XXX"),0),0) `does not represent an advantage over `=MATCH("XXX", A:A ,0)` which you might also code as follows: `Dim num as Variant` followed e.g. by a latebound `num = Application.Match("XXX", Sheet1.Range("A1:A500,0"), 0)`. The variant declaration allows to specify an error via `If IsError(num)` or `If Not IsNumeric(num)` eventually. In any case I'd try to reduce the searchable range indication.  @saho

Comment: Corrected typo: `num = Application.Match("XXX", Tabelle1.Range("A1:A500"), 0)` - *side note: match is case independant*.

Answer (score -1):

One possible issue is that the range "A:A" is not properly defined. Instead of using "A:A", you should specify the worksheet and the range of cells you want to search, such as "Sheet1!A:A" or "Sheet1!A1:A1000".

Another issue could be that the value "XXX" might not exist in column A or it might be in different case. You should check the spelling and case of the value you are searching for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I specified the sheet name and checked the value "XXX" exists in the range.
Then I got an error such as "Type mismatch"
So I changed the type from Integer to Variant and tried it again, but I still got the same error.
If you know how I get the value from worksheetFunction.

Best,
Saho